# Joining multiple tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query matches userID's to eachother based off of total score difference. I have two tables, survey & users.

I need to join this to the users table that I have that has usernames/photo links.

The columns I need displayed are users.name & users.photo. All tables currently have a unique userID, which is users.id, and survey.id that helps match users across DB's.

Could anyone give me a hand as how I could get this done? I've been having a lot of trouble figuring this out, thanks in advance.

```
select a.id yourId, 
b.id matchId, 
abs(a.q1 - b.q1) + abs(a.q2 - b.q2) + abs(a.q3 - b.q3)+ abs(a.q4 - b.q4)+ 
abs(a.q5 - b.q5)+ abs(a.q6 - b.q6)+ abs(a.q7 - b.q7)+ abs(a.q8 - b.q8)+ 
abs(a.q9 - b.q9)+ abs(a.q10 - b.q10) scorediff
from surveys as a
inner join surveys as b on a.id != b.id
WHERE a.id=1
order by scorediff asc
```

Currently this is the results of that query:

```
| yourID|  matchID|  scoreDiff|
----------------------------
| 5     |   2     |      14   |
| 5     |   3     |      25   |
| 5     |   1     |      33   | 
| 5     |   6     |      34   |
```

I would like this as the result:

```
| yourID|  matchID|  scoreDiff| name | photo |
----------------------------------------------
| 5     |   2     |      14   | john | url
| 5     |   3     |      25   | steve| url
| 5     |   1     |      33   | jane | url
| 5     |   6     |      34   | kelly| url
```

matchID can be matched to the users.ID column, as they are all unique to the user.

Comment: Sample data and expected results please

Comment: editing now - sorry

Comment: Trust me. As long as you persist with this schema, you're never going to get anywhere.

Comment: What Strawberry means is....tables and fields should not be 1 character in length, just like the same thing is true of variables, filenames, etc., etc..  Also, if you name fields 1-n, that is bad (unscaleable).

Comment: This is the main thing that doesn't make sense to me in your code: inner join surveys as b on a.id != b.id

Comment: @HoldOffHunger/@Strawberry Thank's for the feedback, it's too late to change this now. This was the schema that was presented to me to work with. I will definitely keep it in mind for future schema's though.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger: It's almost a cross join, but not quite -- it avoids joining a survey with itself, with the apparent goal being to find other surveys `b` being most like `a`. Scales horribly, but it does work.

Comment: It would help if you showed the CREATE TABLE statements too.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Clearly explain the contents of your base tables. Don't clarify in comments, edit your question. PS Do not settle for "the schema that was presented to me to work with", tell someone in authority that it is an inappropriate format for querying and only appropriate for display to people. You need info from some table(s) from which it was generated, not a pivoted version of that.

Answer (score 0):

add a new column with a foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE surveys
ADD COLUMN id_user REFERENCES user(id);
```

or the opposite if that's what you want.  Not sure if that is mysql syntax.

you can then join the tables via

```
WHERE u.id = s.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

This should (also) be a comment, but its a bit long.

> on a.id != b.id

Given the logic elsewhere, this means you are going to get each combination of "surveys" listed twice. Why not:

> on a.id<b.id

(note that if there is an index on index.id, this could actually result in the qquery going slower than it would in the absence of an index using both the above join expressions)

> abs(a.q1 - b.q1) + abs(a.q2 - b.q2)

so you have multiple values represented as different attributes on the same relation. This is not good. It breaks the rules about normalization and makes your life much more difficult. (and ours).

Also, that you are adding the abs of the difference, to my mind, creates a rather distorted picture of the difference between individuals.

Consider:

```
user     q     score
george   1     4
symcbean 1     2
george   2     2
symcbean 2     4
```

Here, by your calculation there is a difference in score of 4 between the 2 users - but I would have interpreted the data above as meaning that the two users had the same score. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. The reason I used
    on a.id !=b.id
is because I want all the users scoreDiff values, and on the front end I am only displaying the 5 lowest "scoreDiff" values as possible matches.

Basically what we are doing is a survey of 10 questions that are scored 1-5 based off how strongly someone agrees. We then take the absolute difference of each question from the previous users and come up with a list of "matches' based off the users who have the least difference. The idea is that the closer to "0" the closer they match with your answers.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed - it still results in combinations being returned twice. It would have been helpful if you'd made your objective clear in the problem statement. You really need to normalize your data.